# Calling a method in one viewmodel from a different viewmodel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I'm developing with MVVMLight on a Windows Phone 8.1 app. We have a setting for sorting a list of users by first or last name. After changing this setting (performed by a ListPicker binded to a property in SettingsViewModel), I want to call a method in a different view model (OtherViewModel) to re-sort a list of users on OtherViewModel's corresponding view. A settingsStore is being used to store the sort setting on the user's phone.

I'd prefer not to create view model dependencies by way of `var vm = new ViewModel()`, since there is not a parent/child relationship between the two view models. I've been told a delegate would be a good choice, but I'm not very familiar with how I'd implement a solution using a delegate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Settings View

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ContactsSortParametersListPicker"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsSortParameters, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ContactsSortParametersSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionChanged="ContactsSortParametersListPicker_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Settings View  (code-behind)

```
private void ContactsSortParametersListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        // want to call method from MainViewModel that updates a list in Main View
}
```

SettingsViewModel

```
public IEnumerable<SortOptions> ContactsSortParameters
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<SortOptions>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortOptions)); }
}

private SortOptions _sortContactsParameterSelected;
public SortOptions ContactsSortParametersSelected
{
    get { return _sortContactsParameterSelected; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _sortContactsParameterSelected, value);
        _settingsStore.ContactsSortParameter = _sortContactsParameterSelected;
    }
}
```

OtherViewModel

```
public async Task LoadDirectory()
{ 
    ...relevant logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MVVM Light, I assume that you have ViewModelLocator instance in your App.xaml resources defined like below.

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPApp.ViewModel" x:Key="Locator" />
```

In your settings view code behind:

```
private async void ContactsSortParametersListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  await ((ViewModelLocator)App.Current.Resources["Locator"]).OtherViewModel.LoadDirectory();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for being new to MVVM. Thanks for your help!